# Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time (with reference to nested element)

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

**Can you advise me how to change this design to make it compile?**

I want to `acquire` a mutable reference to an element of the collection, write through it and (once I don't need it anymore) `release` it.

```
use std::{collections::VecDeque, str::FromStr};

struct Elem {
    value: String,
    flag: bool,
}

impl Default for Elem {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { value: Default::default(), flag: false }
    }
}

struct ProdCons {
    buffer: VecDeque<Elem>,
    foo: bool
}

impl ProdCons {
    fn acquire(&mut self) -> &mut Elem {
        self.foo = true;

        self.buffer.push_back(Default::default());

        let elem = self.buffer.back_mut().unwrap();
        elem.flag = true;

        self.foo = false;

        return elem
    }

    fn release(&mut self, elem: &mut Elem) {
        self.foo = true;

        elem.flag = false;

        self.foo = false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut pc = ProdCons{ buffer: VecDeque::new(), foo: false };

    let elem = pc.acquire();
    elem.value = String::from_str("test").unwrap();

    pc.release(elem);
}
```

Currently, however, the code doesn't compile:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `pc` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:50:5
   |
47 |     let elem = pc.acquire();
   |                ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
...
50 |     pc.release(elem);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^----^
   |     |          |
   |     |          first borrow later used here
   |     second mutable borrow occurs here
```

My understanding is that it's because `pc` is already mutably borrowed, because Rust cannot guarantee that changing it wouldn't change the `elem`.

On the other hand, I *know* that the `release` function is the place where I will stop needing `elem`. How can I express this with Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that it's because `pc` is already mutably borrowed, because Rust cannot guarantee that changing it wouldn't change the `elem`.

Yes, but the compiler *could* perform this analysis. It doesn't, because if it did, then you couldn't tell from looking at the documentation, or the function signature, what the requirements imposed by calling the function would be — and whether a program compiled would depend on *implementation details* like whether the function accesses a certain field or not.

So, instead: `ProdCons::acquire()` takes a `&mut ProdCons`, which means that the *entire* `ProdCons` may be subject to mutation.

The solution is to move where you perform your flag updates — instead of performing them in a separate `release` function, perform them in a “guard” that is created by `acquire()`. Then, to make the code more idiomatic and less error-prone, eliminate `release()` entirely and do the work in `drop()`.

The new code to do this:

```rust
impl ProdCons {
    fn acquire(&mut self) -> Guard<'_> {
        ...
        Guard {
            elem,
            foo: &mut self.foo,
        }
    }
}

struct Guard<'a> {
    elem: &'a mut Elem,
    foo: &'a mut bool,
}
impl Deref for Guard<'_> {
    type Target = Elem;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        self.elem
    }
}
impl DerefMut for Guard<'_> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut *self.elem
    }
}
impl Drop for Guard<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        *self.foo = true;
        self.elem.flag = false;
        *self.foo = false;
    }
}
```

If you want to acquire *more than one* element before the release/drop, you will need to reach for run-time borrow checking a.k.a. *interior mutability*. Some possible solutions in that case:

- Build your structure on top of [`typed-arena`](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/latest/typed_arena/) which is append-and-then-mutate in the same way your current code is, but allows further appending while mutable references still exist.
- Use `std::sync::Mutex` (or a non-thread-safe `std::cell::RefCell`) which lets you “borrow” the item any time with run-time checking, so it doesn't have to be obvious *to the compiler* that the pattern is okay.

  In this case (and in many similar cases), you will also need to wrap each `Mutex` in a `std::sync::Arc`: `Arc<Mutex<Elem>>`. This is so that the compiler can be assured that further accesses to the structure won't drop the `Mutex` while it is in the middle of being used — instead, each acquire/insert/whatever will return a cloned `Arc` so the caller can keep the element alive as long as it needs to, even if it was removed from the collection. (This might not make sense as a possibility from the perspective of your application, but it is a straightforward way for the compiler to be able to verify your program is sound — has no use-after-free bugs.)

---

Complete program with the above code:

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};
use std::{collections::VecDeque, str::FromStr};

struct Elem {
    value: String,
    flag: bool,
}

impl Default for Elem {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { value: Default::default(), flag: false }
    }
}

struct ProdCons {
    buffer: VecDeque<Elem>,
    foo: bool
}

impl ProdCons {
    fn acquire(&mut self) -> Guard<'_> {
        self.foo = true;

        self.buffer.push_back(Default::default());

        let elem = self.buffer.back_mut().unwrap();
        elem.flag = true;

        self.foo = false;

        Guard {
            elem,
            foo: &mut self.foo,
        }
    }
}

struct Guard<'a> {
    elem: &'a mut Elem,
    foo: &'a mut bool,
}

impl Deref for Guard<'_> {
    type Target = Elem;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        self.elem
    }
}
impl DerefMut for Guard<'_> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut *self.elem
    }
}

impl Drop for Guard<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        *self.foo = true;
        self.elem.flag = false;
        *self.foo = false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut pc = ProdCons{ buffer: VecDeque::new(), foo: false };

    {
        let mut elem = pc.acquire();
        elem.value = String::from_str("test").unwrap();
    }
    assert_eq!(pc.foo, false);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. I'm marking it as solving the problem.

Comment: I'd ask for more tips, towards making this program more complete.

* Why the typed-arena? In fact, I will want to add multiple objects, and keep mutable references to them. Can I achieve the same without external library, just for the sake of exercise?
* If I then want to make this usable in multi-threaded context, will the require a complete change of design, or can this iteratively be extended?

Comment: @sthlm58 In that case you need `Mutex`, not `typed-arena`. I've added a section to my answer on that. • “Can I achieve the same without external library” — yes, absolutely, but it requires writing `unsafe` code to implement interior mutability, which is a difficult task, and one of the things that keeps Rust programs free of bugs is _not writing unnecessary unsafe code._